# data driven framework with java for drop down

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, data-driven

I am creating data in excel for DataDriven framework.I am getting problem how to use that data if there is drop down.

example- for Travelling site there is drop-down list of cites in arrival list

If I am keeping all cites name in excel how to use it in framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TestNG](http://testng.org/) unit testing framework here since you are using Java. especially [@dataprovider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) example. For code of fetching data from excel, you can use [JExcel api.](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).

Below code will run same test case one by one for each city in excel file and select from dropdown. See below code for more reference :

```
@Test(dataProvider = "DP1")
public void selectCityFromDropDown(String city) throws Exception {
    // Selenium webdriver code for selecting city from  drop down.
}

@DataProvider(name = "DP1")
public Object[][] createData1() throws Exception {
    // code to open excel file, fetch data from excel file and generate two dimentional array of String/Object class so that it can be returned back to test case
}
```